# depending on json response to take the inputs

Tags: php, html, json, forms

I will get a server response which is in json format,below is the json response like this  there are many oragnisations,out of which only one organisation is default organisation,so there are chances of getting a bigger json on each time when the organisation changes ,corresponding to organistion there is a form field for location in my` html form  in which i have to select one location from many of these,on selecting the location,there is another form field called building there will come many values on selecting one,there will another web service

```
[{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"}]
```

Comment: What is your question? 
Could you possibly clean up the question so it is more organized in sentences and perhaps paragraphs? I found it very hard to follow, only to find out there wasn't an actual question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried upto this, in this i am supposed to call a web service ,that will send a json response which contain organisation names,after selecting the organisation name ,some organisations can have more than one location ,so only the corresponding locations of the selected organisation must show up in the location drop box after that there an option called building in which certain location can have more than one buildings so only the buildings of the selected location must show up in the buildings combo box.

here is the code i have completed

```
<head>
    <title>PROFILE INFORMATION OF USER</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>  
</head>
<body>
<div id="contact"><?php
session_start();
$url='my web service';
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($useridofuser));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
    $response=  curl_exec($ch);
   // echo('\n'."Server response : \n \n".$response);
    curl_close($ch);
    //parsing the json response from server
    $jsonde="$response";
 $org = array();
$loc = array();
$bui = array();
$items = json_decode($response);
foreach( $items as $each ){
$loc[]=$each->location[0]->name;
$bui[]=$each->location[0]->building[0];
$org[]=$each->name;
}
?>
<select name="category_id">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
foreach($org as $key=>$val)
{?>
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php 
echo $_SESSION['organisation'];
?></option>

 <?php
 }
 ?>
</select>
<select name="category_id">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
foreach($loc as $key=>$val)
{?>
<option value="<?php //echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<select name="category_id">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
foreach($bui as $key=>$val)
{?>
<option value="<?php //echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```